# Maven UI Project configuration with web project

Tags: java, maven

I have created multi module maven structure.
Everything works fine but the problem is that i separated my Java Web application into two part.
One if for UI and second is for web application configuration to separate UI logic.
My UI project only contain HTML,CSS,JS,IMAGES files and Web project contain spring configuration and web services and etc.
After searching i came to know that with the use of overlays we can combine war of the UI to Web app.
But the problem is that if i change the html or css or js file i need to build the Web application than and than i can reflect the changes of UI project.
So is there any solution to automate the changes of UI in web app.
My Web App projects pom.xml is as follow.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>OverlayUI</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and overlays logic as in build section:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <overlays>
                <overlay>
                    <groupId>OverlayDemo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>OverlayUI</artifactId>
                </overlay>
            </overlays>                    
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Why not have two separate projects - UI and WebApp - each project can be built separately. The WebApp project has a dependency on the UI project and will include UI files when the WebApp is built. Alternately, you can also have a parent project with two children projects (WebApp and UI).

Comment: I think I understood how your project is designed but I don't understand your expectations. It is normal in Maven that if you change low level project you must rebuild project tree starting from low level to propagate changes to high level project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my expectation is that UI project changes can automatic reflect in web project as I need to change HTML,CSS or JS File frequently Or any other solution so that I don't have to built the UI Project?